# Search a data on a sheet and show its contents in a textbox VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement a simple program in vba and the following problem arises: How do you find a cell data in excel and put all the associated data in the textbox?
For example:
How to make that when typing the name I load the document, the data 1, 2, 3 and the average in the respective textbox.

[image: This is my sheet]

I try to do it with this code, but I do not understand its operation very well, it only works for me if I search for the document

```
Private Sub btnBuscar_Click()

On Error GoTo NE

buscarCedula = InputBox("Search:")

Sheets("Hoja1").Select
Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Find(What:=buscarCedula, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

txtCedula.Text = ActiveCell
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

txtNombre.Text = ActiveCell
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

txtNotaUno.Text = ActiveCell
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

txtNotaDos.Text = ActiveCell
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

txtNotaTres.Text = ActiveCell
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

lblNotaDefinitiva.Caption = ActiveCell
```

Any idea or example that can guide me?

Comment: Are you saying that your code works when searching for the "Document" (because your code is searching for it in the column from cell A4 down), and you now want to know how to search in cell B4 down instead (so that you can search for names instead of documents) or are you wanting to search in both column A **and** B so that the user can search for either a document **or** a name?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is Concatenate. You want all the data from C4:F4 to show up in A1:F1. If so, in A1:F1 type the following formula (or copy+paste).

=Concatenate(C4,D4,E4,F4)

if you want spaces in between do the following:

=Concatenate(C4," ",D4," ",E4," ",F4)

If this is what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to gather the data and then put it into a textbox.  You should be explicitly referencing the ranges and cells, instead of implicitly by using activecell and select.  This is just a snippet to get you on the correct direction.

```
Set sh = Sheets("Hoja1")
    'this searches column a for your input and brings back the row number
rw = sh.Range("A:A").Find(What:=buscarCedula, LookIn:= _
    xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext).Row
    'these set some variable equal to the columns in the found row so you can put them into a textbox.
doc = sh.Cells(1, rw).Value
Name = sh.Cells(2, rw).Value
Data1 = sh.Cells(3, rw).Value
Data2 = sh.Cells(4, rw).Value
```